# Trying to change values within an XML file with Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have an XML file that I need to programmatically change with Powershell. I have searched throughout this site and Google, and none of the answers I've found have worked.

The XML looks like this:

```
<Terminal>
    <ID>13</ID>
    <TerminalType>0</TerminalType>
    <Name>T13 TA BAR     </Name>
    <StoreID>1</StoreID>
    <IPAddress>10.10.10.101</IPAddress>
    <SubnetMask>255.255.255.0</SubnetMask>
    <DHCP>false</DHCP>
    <Workgroup>*NONE</Workgroup>
    <CreateBootDrvShare>true</CreateBootDrvShare>
    <TimeZone>Eastern Standard Time</TimeZone>
    <DaylightSavings>true</DaylightSavings>
    <TerminalReload>true</TerminalReload>  
    <NumTerms>-1</NumTerms>
    <Status>1</Status>
    <EnableVNC>false</EnableVNC>
    <StandaloneInterfaceServer>false</StandaloneInterfaceServer>
    <AKTerminalPrefix>-1</AKTerminalPrefix>
    <AKUseTouch>false</AKUseTouch>
</Terminal>
```

There will be a number of these blocks within the XML document, one for each "computer" being used. I need to be able to change the IP address based on the ID of terminal. How would I go about this?

I tried the following, which did not work:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)
$xml.SelectNodes("//Terminal")
```

Also:

```
$xml.Terminal | Where-Object {$_.Terminal.ID -eq '1' } | Select-Object IPAddress
```

Which also did not work.

If say the ID of the "computer" is 5, I want the IP address to be:

```
<IPAddress>10.10.10.105</IPAddress>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of your examples is really close to working. You can just do the following:

```
$XMLOutputFile = "Path\file.xml"
$xml = [xml](Get-Content $file)    
($xml.Terminal | Where-Object {$_.ID -eq '5' }).IPAddress = '10.10.10.105'
$xml.Save($XMLOutputFile)
```

Once you have an XML object (using the `[xml]` type accelerator in this case), you can just update properties using the `$object.property = value` syntax. Then all that is left is handling the output. `.Save()` saves the XML document to file.

Comment: This does not seem to be working.  Getting:  The property 'IPAddress' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.

Comment: @Harlan your xml structure must be slightly different than your XML example. Do you have two levels of Terminal?

Comment: No. I typed the XML exactly as shown. `<Terminal>` is the first level, and directly below that is both `<ID>` and `<IPAddress>`.

Comment: Nevermind. I figured it out. I did have one level above `<Terminal>`. `<ConfigurationData>`. So the actual line is `($ralxml.ConfigurationData.Terminal | Where-Object { $_.ID -eq '5' }).IPAddress = '10.10.10.105'`